# PDF which is uploaded is not showing in Syncfusion PDF Viewer?

Tags: java, syncfusion

I'm trying to upload a file from my local machine and i need to display the uploaded file using SyncFusion PDF viewer. I'm converting the uploaded file to base64 String and then loading that data. But i'm seeing 500 error in the console.

I'm converting the uploaded file to base64 String and then loading that data. But i'm seeing 500 error in the console. Below is the code that i have tried

```
  public service: string;
   constructor() 
   {
      this.service = 
    'http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/ejservices/api/PdfViewer';
   }
    readFile(evt) 
   { 
        var upoadedFiles = evt.target.files;
        var uploadedFile = upoadedFiles[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(uploadedFile);
         reader.onloadend = function () { 
                this.base64 = reader.result; 
                var pdfviewerObject = 
       document.getElementById('pdfViewer').ej2_instances[0]; 
                //load the base64 string 
                pdfviewerObject.load(this.base64); 
            }   

}
```

On uploading the file i'm getting 500 error code as my response.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided details we found that you have provided the EJ1 PDF Viewer service URL in the code instead of providing the EJ2 PdfViewer service URL (https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/pdfviewer). Please find the below KB to getting started with EJ2 PDF Viewer with the sample at the end of the KB ,

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10473/how-to-get-started-with-syncfusion-angular-7-pdfviewer-component 
Web Service: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10346/how-to-create-pdf-viewer-web-service-application-in-asp-net-core

UG link : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/pdfviewer/getting-started/

Also please find the below KB link to load document as base64 in PDF Viewer,
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10549/how-to-load-the-blob-storage-url-in-the-pdf-viewer